# fAccessWindow ("Hide", False, False) gives compilation error

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2010

fAccessWindow ("Hide", False, False) function for hiding actual access window gives compilation error number 7960

I have tried without space "fAccessWindow("Hide", False, False)" but no difference. I also have code below in a module which can be also found [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2562). I'm using Access 2010 with lowest level of macro security. Also my operating system is x64.

```
Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Dim dwReturn As Long

Const SW_HIDE = 0
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Public Function fAccessWindow(Optional Procedure As String, Optional SwitchStatus As Boolean, Optional StatusCheck As Boolean) As Boolean
If Procedure = "Hide" Then
    dwReturn = ShowWindow(Application.hWndAccessApp, SW_HIDE)
End If
If Procedure = "Show" Then
    dwReturn = ShowWindow(Application.hWndAccessApp, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
End If
If Procedure = "Minimize" Then
    dwReturn = ShowWindow(Application.hWndAccessApp, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED)
End If
If SwitchStatus = True Then
    If IsWindowVisible(hWndAccessApp) = 1 Then
        dwReturn = ShowWindow(Application.hWndAccessApp, SW_HIDE)
    Else
        dwReturn = ShowWindow(Application.hWndAccessApp, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
    End If
End If
If StatusCheck = True Then
    If IsWindowVisible(hWndAccessApp) = 0 Then
        fAccessWindow = False
    End If
    If IsWindowVisible(hWndAccessApp) = 1 Then
        fAccessWindow = True
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: First, you're not showing the code that you say is causing the compilation error (you're showing the code being called, but not the code calling it that's generating the error); second, you're not showing the actual error message you're getting. Please provide those details in order for people to be able to help you.

Comment: "There was an error compiling this function" then macro name, action name "RunCode", arguments "fAccessWindow ("Hide", False, False)" error number "7960"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to [this article from MS on 64-bit VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831%28office.14%29.aspx) and use not just PtrSafe, but also the new LongLong data type, and you'll need to use conditional compilation:

```
  #if Win64 then
      Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongLong) As LongLong
  #else
      Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
  #end if
```

I am not programming for 64-bit Access so have not worked with this. It is unclear to me what the interaction between the Win64 and VBA7 compilation constants are, and the cited article isn't exactly clear on it. It's not clear to me if you should do this:

```
  #If Win64 And VBA7 Then
      ...
  #Else
      ...
  #End If
```

or if it should be:

```
  #If Win64 Then
      #If VBA7 Then
         ...
      #Else
         ...
      #End If
  #Else
      #If VBA7 Then
         ...
      #Else
         ...
      #End If
  #End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added PtrSafe option to functions below and it started to work in x64 but now it is giving same error on x86 machines.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32"_
    (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
```